# Que estoy haciendo mal con este código en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Yo soy un principiante en la programación, y recién estoy iniciando mi materia de Programación en la universidad, y esta es 1 de 2 clases que tengo, que es hacer un programa o código que cuando ingreses la edad el programa te diga si eres un adulto o un bebe o un niño ETC...

Se que tiene muchos errores, pero todavía no se como resolverlos. Se los agradecería un millón si pudieran ayudar a este principiante.

Aquí esta el programa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/*Please dont change namespace, Dcoder 
and class must not be public*/

//Compiler version 4.0, .NET Framework 4.5


namespace Dcoder
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Enum     

            UstedesunBebe = 0-2;
            UstedesunNino = 3-12;
            UstedesunAdolecente = 13-17;
            Ustedesunadulto = 18-150;
                //Your code goes here
                Console.WriteLine("Hello, Dcoder!");
int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


if ((num=0&<2))
{
    //UstedesunBebe


Console.WriteLine (''UstedesunBebe'');
}

if ((num=>3) && (<12))
{
    //UstedesunNino


Console.WriteLine (''Ustedesunniño'');
} 

if ((num=>13) && (<18))
{
    //UstedesunAdolecente


Console.WriteLine (''Ustedesunadolecente'');
} 

if ((num>=18))
{
    //UstedesunAdulto


Console.WriteLine (''UstedesunAdulto'');
} 


Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Josmer, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo leer [ask], hacer el [tour] (y ganar así tu primera medalla) y aprender a hacer un [mcve]. Tienes muchos errores simplemente de compilación. Empieza por ahí. Tienes que tener en cuenta que lo primero es intentarlo tú (y el primer paso es quitar los errores de compilación)

Comment: Fíjate, por ejemplo, en tus operadores lógicos (>=, <, etc.) Estás poniendo, el mismo operador (>=), de distintas formas (=>, >=)

Comment: Las cadenas se especifican con comillas dobles (`"`), andas poniendo dos comillas simples (`'`)...

Comment: Chicos, esto ni siquiera compila. de ninguna forma. yo encararia esto de otra forma.

Comment: Gente, si respondo con un código diferente, pero que funciona me llenarán de negativos?

Comment: @Jemonge esta aprendiendo. la idea no es resolverle el ejercicio. Tiene que aprender por si mismo a hacerlo. si no, cuando va a aprender?

Comment: @gbianchi Sí, eso pensé.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Voy a marcar tus errores:

1. [Enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) es una estructura de datos que sirve para Enumerar de alguna forma, un conjunto de datos. No es lo que queres en este caso, y no te sirve para nada.
2. La instrución [if](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) es una estructura de control que sirve para comparar valores. Sin embargo, en todos los casos, hay que especificar los valores a comparar.

O sea que se necesita si o si que los valores esten especificados.

Esto no es valido:

```
if ((num=0&<2))
```

Y como si fuera poco, num no puede ser igual a cero y menor que dos al mismo tiempo ;)

Debe ser asi:

```
if (num>0 && num<=2)
```

3. El operador de comparación [`and`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator) en C# es `&&`
4. Los strings en C# van entre comillas ", no entre un par de comillas simples. Esto " es distinto que esto ' dos veces.
5. El operador de comparación es [>=](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/greater-than-equal-operator)
6. EL operador = es un operador de asignación. Si haces `num = 0`, estas diciendo que la variable num tendra el valor 0. Para comparar, se utiliza el operador [==](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator)

Fijate que todas esas cosas estan documentadas. No le tengas miedo a la documentación. Va a ser tu mejor aliada en el futuro.

Comment: Ya esta claro que el operador Enum no se utiliza ahí, entonces debería utilizar Int?

Comment: @JosmerSuero ni se que intentaste hacer con ese enum ahi, asi que ni puedo contestarte porque no se cual fue tu idea

Comment: Y además, num=0 no compara num a 0, da el valor 0 a num.  Para comparar, quiere num==0

Comment: Ahora lo agrego como otro error @Duston. Gracias

Comment: Ya he resuelto algunos de los problemas ya mencionados, lo publico debajo de este comentario? ya que viendo el programa anterior se siguen mencionando los mismos problemas

Comment: @JosmerSuero resuelve tus problemas de a uno. Si resolviste todos los problemas, y tu programa compila (antes no lo hacia) avanzaste un monton. Si no compila, fijate que errores tira el compilador, y corregilos. los comentarios son para aclaraciones, no vas a poder poner tu codigo en tu comentario, y no cambies tu pregunta. Si queres, editala, pero no borres lo que esta. Igual, mi respuesta va a quedar invalida o voy a tener que editarla mil veces por cada cambio que hagas ;)

Comment: Si!. He podido avanzar un buen poco, solo me quedan 4 errores del tipo CS0103

Comment: @JosmerSuero a ver muestra la linea que te tira el error. eso es que estas usando un nombre de variable o un nombre de algo, que no definiste antes

Comment: Estos 4 tienen el mismo error:
            UstedEsUnBebe = 0-2;
            UstedEsUnNino = 3-12;
            UstedEsUnAdolecente = 13-17;
            UstedEsUnAdulto = 18-150;

Comment: y eso que es? que son esas lineas? en que contexto? estas tratando de definir variables? las variables tienen un solo valor, no un rango de valores. para que se supone que tenes esas lineas?

Comment: Estoy tratando de definar o declarar esas variables, para que mas adelante cuando el usuario ingrese su edad, le diga si es un niño, o un bebe o un adulto.

Comment: Pero eso ya lo haces en los condicionales.. las variables tienen un solo valor. No tienen un rango de valores. No tienen sentido todas esas variables. Si las borras, tu programa funciona. @JosmerSuero

Comment: Muchas Gracias @gbianchi y a todos los demás que me pudieron ayudar, repito soy un principiante en todo esto, tengo mucho mas que aprender, y al rato tengo otro programa que hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Inicia con algo mas simple, entiende como introduces la edad y muestras la salida,

```
public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Escriba su edad:");
          int edad = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

          //con esto solo obtienes la variable edad.

          //Lo siguiente como funciona un if
          // con WriteLine mostruestras la salida


         Console.ReadLine();//esto para que se quede en espera la pantalla y no se cierre.           

        }
   }
```

una vez entendido eso investiga como hacer un if intenta solo if simples, por ultimo
 agrega todas las condiciones:
            UstedesunBebe = 0-2;
            UstedesunNino = 3-12;
            UstedesunAdolecente = 13-17;
            Ustedesunadulto = 18-150;

saludos.